# Cancel a  dialog created using AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog.Builder` inside which a  button is present  and I want to  dismiss the dialog  when it is clicked.

But there are no `.dismiss()` or `.cancel()` methods.

```
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.map_window, null);

    window = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    window.setCancelable(true);

    buttonStar = (ImageButton)layout.findViewById(R.id.buttonStar);
    buttonStar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
    buttonStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //finishing window;
    }
      });


    window.setPositiveButton("Volver", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int wichButton) {  

        }  
    });  

    window.show();

}
```

Comment: There's definitely `cancel()` method on Dialog.

Comment: There's a `cancel()`   and a `dismiss()`  method for sure. :) .  `dialog.dismiss()`  or `dialog.cancel()` will do  the corresponding function.

Comment: window.dismiss and window.cancel don't exist http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html I need a dialog as two people answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`AlertDialog.Builder#show`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show%28%29) returns the `AlertDialog` itself, so just get the AlertDialog itself that returns from `show` and call dismiss on it:

```
AlertDialog dialog;
//...

dialog = window.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try canceling it from dialog object. Create a dialog object as follows:

```
Dialog dialog = window.create();
dialog.cancel()
```

Comment: @user1256477 - No, just decide whichever you prefer.

Comment: No... Lol ... accept the answer which you think better helps you. But do vote those who you think somehow helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

find the bellow code for AlertDialog. use new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() instead of onClick().

```
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainCatalogueActivity.this)

                    .setTitle("Server Response Error")

                    .setMessage("some message ")

                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel)

                    .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                            startActivity(intent);

                            finish();


                        }
                    }).create();
    ad.show();
```